# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'; did you mean 'NSLayoutManagerDelegate'?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location

I'm using Swift class in my existing Object-C project.In my Swift class, I'm using `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Everything works well. However, when `ProjectName-Swift.h` is generated, an issue in `ProjectName-Swift.h` file shows "Can't find protocol declaration for 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'". I tried to silence the issue by importing `CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h` in `ProjectName-Swift.h`. It worked. But after compiled a few times, `CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h` was gone because `ProjectName-Swift.h` is generated from my swift class. And the issue comes again.

Comment: I think you have to create ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file for it.

Comment: I have added #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> in bridging header also. But not working.

Comment: Can you please show me your code and file structure. Or send me your project on my email.

Comment: same issue face but i am importing   #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> and working fine now

Comment: How do you solve it? I have the same error. @ShahbazAkram Where place #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>?

Comment: @djardon place in header file